# setContentView in ActionBarActivity and FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-support-library, android-actionbaractivity

In FragmentActivity, the order of super.onCreate and setContentView isn't important, why?

**FragmentActivity**

```
//OK
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting_for_confirmation_order);
}

//OK
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting_for_confirmation_order);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

But in ActionBarActivity, it throws a NullPointerException.

**ActionBarActivity**

```
//OK
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting_for_confirmation_order);
}

//ERROR
@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_waiting_for_confirmation_order); //NullPointerException
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: If you look at `ActionBarActivity's` source code, you will see that it uses ` ActionBarActivityDelegate` instance internally - this is initialized inside `ActionBarActivity#onCreate()`. So, if you call `setContentView(...)` before `super.onCreate(...)`, a `NullPointerException` occurs because `setContentView(...)` calls `ActionBarActivityDelegate#setContentView(layoutResID);` => and `ActionBarActivityDelegate` instance is `null` at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `ActionBarActivity` (from support-v7) is using a delegate object to either use the real implementation or the compat implementation.

This delegate is instantiated in the method onCreate() of `ActionBarActivity` and the method `setContentView()` of ActionBarActivity is simply doing `delegate.setContentView()`.

That's why there's a NPE if you call `setContentView()` before `onCreate()`.

In `FragmentActivity`, (or standard Activity actually), the order doesn't matter because `setContentView()` doesn't rely on a specific object that could have been instantiated in `onCreate()`.